# iOS Creating an Object Best Practice

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, swift2, ios9

I've created a wizard for user's to sign up using my app, however, I'm having some doubts as to how I should store their information along the way.

I have a `User` model, which is filled out when users are pulled from the database, however, there are some **required** fields on this model that wouldn't be filled out if I were to use it as the object that is passed along as the user goes through the the wizard.

Here is my `User` model:

```
final class User: NSObject, ResponseObjectSerializable, ResponseCollectionSerializable {
    let id: Int
    var facebookUID: String?
    var email: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var phone: String?
    var position: String?
    var thumbnail: UIImage?
    var timeCreated: CVDate

    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, var representation: AnyObject) {
        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [String: AnyObject]) {
            representation = dataRepresentation
        }

        self.id = representation.valueForKeyPath("id") as! Int
        self.facebookUID = (representation.valueForKeyPath("facebook_UID") as? String)
        self.email = (representation.valueForKeyPath("email") as? String) ?? ""
        self.firstName = (representation.valueForKeyPath("first_name") as? String) ?? ""
        self.lastName = (representation.valueForKeyPath("last_name") as? String) ?? ""
        self.phone = (representation.valueForKeyPath("phone") as? String)
        self.position = (representation.valueForKeyPath("position_name") as? String)
        self.thumbnail = UIImage(named: "ThomasBaldwin")

        if let timeCreated = representation.valueForKeyPath("time_created") as? String {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
            if let date = formatter.dateFromString(timeCreated) {
                self.timeCreated = CVDate(date: date)
            } else {
                self.timeCreated = CVDate(date: NSDate())
            }
        } else {
            self.timeCreated = CVDate(date: NSDate())
        }
    }

    static func collection(response response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [User] {
        var users: [User] = []

        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [NSDictionary]) {
            if let dataRepresentation = dataRepresentation as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for userRepresentation in dataRepresentation {
                    if let user = User(response: response, representation: userRepresentation) {
                        users.append(user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return users
    }
}
```

Notice the variables `id` and `timeCreated`. These are both generated when a new row is added to the `Users` table in the database, therefore, I wouldn't have values for those variables until the user is actually created.

Also, I would like to add some methods to the model, such as `validateUser` which will be a method that makes sure all the fields are filled out, and `validateEmail` which will be a method that makes sure the email is in proper syntax, and so on...

My question is, should I
**A.** just make those constants optional and add those methods to my current `User` model
**B.** make another model called `CreateUserModel` that only has variables for the information the user will be filling out and put the extra methods in there

**UPDATE**

I updated my `User` class to use a dictionary as the storage mechanism and it already looks a lot cleaner. However, the issue that comes to mind is, how will another programmer know which fields he can grab from the `User` model since I'm not individually storing them as variables anymore. Would they just have to check the DB and look at the structure of the table?

Here's my updated User class:

```
final class User: NSObject, ResponseObjectSerializable, ResponseCollectionSerializable {

    var properties = NSDictionary()

    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [String: AnyObject]) {
            properties = dataRepresentation
        }

        properties = representation as! NSDictionary
    }

    static func collection(response response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [User] {
        var users: [User] = []

        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [NSDictionary]) {
            if let dataRepresentation = dataRepresentation as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for userRepresentation in dataRepresentation {
                    if let user = User(response: response, representation: userRepresentation) {
                        users.append(user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return users
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make them Optionals. That is the beauty of Optionals - you can use `nil` to mean exactly "no data here".

The other grand strategy that comes to mind is to use a dictionary as the storage mechanism inside your model, because that way either it has a certain key or it doesn't. You could make your User object key-value coding compliant, and thus effectively transparent, by passing keys on to the dictionary.

Comment: and adding the validate methods to the User model is the best practice for something like this, right? Or should I be adding it to the controller?

Comment: @Thomas The only question there is: who do you think it is that should _embody the knowledge_ of what it means for a User to be valid? It sounds to me like you think it is the User itself, and that is my gut instinct too. - A good way to look at it is: suppose we changed our spec, or suppose we wanted to reuse User in another app. Surely having User know how to validate itself will give us the most flexibility to do that.

Comment: Thanks @matt. I just have one last question regarding your answer, and I updated my question to show it. Thanks!

Comment: @Thomas Do you know what a "leech" is on Stack Overflow? It's someone who, his question having been answered, keeps coming back and back for more. Don't do that. Your original question was answered. If you have a new question that stems from what you're doing now, _ask a new question_. Thank you.