# Swift Best Practice For Models

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I've created a `User` class and was given a suggestion to use a dictionary as the storage mechanism to make it more flexible and accomplish my needs. Please reference this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249740/ios-creating-an-object-best-practice).

Here is my original `User` model:

```
final class User: NSObject, ResponseObjectSerializable, ResponseCollectionSerializable {
    let id: Int
    var facebookUID: String?
    var email: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var phone: String?
    var position: String?
    var thumbnail: UIImage?
    var timeCreated: CVDate

    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, var representation: AnyObject) {
        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [String: AnyObject]) {
            representation = dataRepresentation
        }

        self.id = representation.valueForKeyPath("id") as! Int
        self.facebookUID = (representation.valueForKeyPath("facebook_UID") as? String)
        self.email = (representation.valueForKeyPath("email") as? String) ?? ""
        self.firstName = (representation.valueForKeyPath("first_name") as? String) ?? ""
        self.lastName = (representation.valueForKeyPath("last_name") as? String) ?? ""
        self.phone = (representation.valueForKeyPath("phone") as? String)
        self.position = (representation.valueForKeyPath("position_name") as? String)
        self.thumbnail = UIImage(named: "ThomasBaldwin")

        if let timeCreated = representation.valueForKeyPath("time_created") as? String {
            let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
            if let date = formatter.dateFromString(timeCreated) {
                self.timeCreated = CVDate(date: date)
            } else {
                self.timeCreated = CVDate(date: NSDate())
            }
        } else {
            self.timeCreated = CVDate(date: NSDate())
        }
    }

    static func collection(response response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [User] {
        var users: [User] = []

        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [NSDictionary]) {
            if let dataRepresentation = dataRepresentation as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for userRepresentation in dataRepresentation {
                    if let user = User(response: response, representation: userRepresentation) {
                        users.append(user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return users
    }
}
```

And here's my updated `User` class using a dictionary as the storing mechanism:

```
final class User: NSObject, ResponseObjectSerializable, ResponseCollectionSerializable {

    var properties = NSDictionary()

    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) {
        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [String: AnyObject]) {
            properties = dataRepresentation
        }

        properties = representation as! NSDictionary
    }

    static func collection(response response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [User] {
        var users: [User] = []

        if let dataRepresentation = ((representation as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("data") as? [NSDictionary]) {
            if let dataRepresentation = dataRepresentation as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for userRepresentation in dataRepresentation {
                    if let user = User(response: response, representation: userRepresentation) {
                        users.append(user)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return users
    }
}
```

The issue that comes to mind though, is how will another programmer know which fields he can grab from the `User` model since I'm not individually storing them as variables anymore. Would they just have to check the DB and look at the structure of the table?

Also the way the `User` class is setup right now, it pretty much could be the model for any table I pull from the database (since I have no `User` model specific methods on it right now) and I can always call `user.properties.valueForKeyPath("column_name")` for any table.

Is it a clean practice if I change the model name to something broader, and reuse it for any table that I'm going to pull data from that I don't need any model specific methods for?

Comment: I agree with @duncanC but if you do want to keep an internal dictionary storage you should create discrete computed properties for the various attributes and use code to access the underlying dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to prefer custom data objects to dictionaries. A custom data object has specific, named fields of concrete types. It's self-documenting, and when you use it you can assume that it has the properties you are expecting and that they are the correct type. With dictionaries you can't assume either (Well, with a Swift dictionary you can enforce typing but then you can't mix properties of different types like a name string and a numeric salary value)